# SharePoint 2010 Updates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I have SharePoint 2010 installed in my production machine & i want to install other patches. My last update on SharePoint 2010 was KB 2687453 (SP2).

Now i want to install all other patches. so do i need to install all from aug-2013 to July-2017 or i just install July-2017 update and it include all other previous patches inside it.

Please check link of all updates [2010 Updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715807(v=office.16).aspx#BKMK_2010)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

July 2017 CU is enough for you. [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2017/07/12/july-2017-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/) is more information about updates.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you have SharePoint 2010 Service pack 2 already installed, you can directly install the July 2017 Cumulative Update.

It will include all the updates from August 2013 to June 2017.

Reference - [July 11, 2017, cumulative update for SharePoint Server 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3213634/july-11-2017-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2010-kb3213634)

I would however recommend that you follow the best practice and install the (N-1) update i.e the June 2017 Update.

Also, you should first install it on a Staging/Test environment first before doing it on production.